# Python thread/process pool on infinite iterator?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I have an iterator function that yields an infinite stream of integers:

```
def all_ints(start=0):
  yield start
  yield all_ints(start+1)
```

I want to have a pool of threads or processes do calculations on these up to $POOLSIZE at a time. Each process will possibly save a result to some shared data structure so I do not need the return value from the process/thread function. It seems to me this use of the python3 Pool would achieve this:

```
# dummy example functions
def check_prime(n):
  return n % 2 == 0

def store_prime(p):
    ''' synchronize, write to some shared structure'''
    pass

p = Pool()

for n in all_ints():
    p.apply_async(check_prime, (n,), callback=store_prime)
```

But when I run this I get a python process that just continually uses more memory (and not from the iterator, that can run for days). I would expect this behavior if I was storing the results of all the apply_async calls, but I am not.

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there another API from the thread pool I should be using?

Comment: First of all: are you using threads or processes? This is important, because threads in Python won't give you any performance boost when doing calculations (due to GIL). Secondly, could you elaborate on what you expect and what is happening? I'm not sure I understand your description.

Comment: I am using processes, but it (the problem) should be the same for either (and yes am aware of the GIL). Second: what I expect to happen is: at most 4 processes run concurrently (meaning p.apply_async blocks sometimes), and the memory usage remains constant (again, ignore the iterator). What I see is runaway memory use that quickly grows to eat all machine memory and gets killed by OOM-- as if I was storing everything returned by p.apply_async.

Comment: You misunderstand how pools work. Neither `apply` nor `apply_async` block when the internal queue of the pool is full. Actually that never happens as long as you have free memory. So your loop spins all the time at 100% cpu, pushing new values to the pool's internal queue. There's the memory leak.

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense! Thanks. I will try to think of a way to make this work..

Comment: You'll probably need a custom pool implementation. I don't think that there's anything in Python's standard library that will suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [Pool.imap_unordered](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered), which uses the pooled processes to apply a function to the elements yielded by an iterator. Its parameter `chunksize` allows you to specify how many items from the iterator are passed to the pool in each step.

Also I would avoid using any shared memory structures for IPC. Just let the "expensive" function sent to the pool return the information you need, and process it in the main process.

Here's an example (where I abort after 200'000 results; if you remove that part, you'll see the processes happily work in a fixed amount of RAM "forever"):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from math import sqrt
import itertools
import time

def check_prime(n): 
    if n == 2: return (n, True)
    if n % 2 == 0 or n < 2: return (n, False)
    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n))+1, 2):
        if n % i == 0: return (n, False)
    return (n, True)    

def main():
    L = 200000   # limit for performance timing 
    p = Pool()
    n_primes = 0
    before = time.time()
    for (n, is_prime) in p.imap_unordered(check_prime, itertools.count(1), 1000):
        if is_prime:
            n_primes += 1
            if n_primes >= L: 
                break
    print("Computed %d primes in %.1fms" % (n_primes, (time.time()-before)*1000.0))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output on my Intel Core i5 (2 Core, 4 Threads):

```
Computed 200000 primes in 15167.9ms
```

Output if I change it to `Pool(1)`, so using just 1 subprocess:

```
Computed 200000 primes in 37909.2ms
```

HTH!

Comment: I just tried this, and I think this is the right solution when the chunksize > 1, so that the unordered iterator returned will be blocking when all processes are busy working on their selection of input. Thanks for this.